# function with parameters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

When I try to run this script on the command line (e.g. call the function) I get the below error. I'm studying and can't quite understand why I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

This is the function:

```py
def assemble_name(last_name = "Jones", first_name = "John"):
  full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
```

(I try calling it with both an empty parameter and once overwrite for first_name to equal "Homer" and it gives the error meaning it gives up on running the code?)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
    assemble_name()
  File "C:\Users\ANYTHINGFORMYCELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\LearnInOneDay\Lists.py", line 33, in assemble_name
    assemble_name(first_name = "Hugo")
  File "C:\Users\ANYTHINGFORMYCELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\LearnInOneDay\Lists.py", line 33, in assemble_name
    assemble_name(first_name = "Hugo")
  File "C:\Users\ANYTHINGFORMYCELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\LearnInOneDay\Lists.py", line 33, in assemble_name
    assemble_name(first_name = "Hugo")
  [Previous line repeated 1022 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: The traceback says your code has a line `assemble_name()` which calls the function. Please show us the code where that is from.

Comment: You are probably calling with parameter inside the function. So it keeps on calling the function recursively resulting in `RecursionError`. Note that indentation matters.

Comment: This function should has no error, please give us the part where the error really occurs.

Comment: assemble_name(),  this function is calling contineously without stopping.  Disclose your code to identify what exactly happening.